# Javafx TableView in a ScrollPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm having some issues with the Constrained Resize Policy for a TableView inside a ScrollPane.
It seems as though the headings do not line up completely with its column. On scroll or resize the columns snap to their correct position.

I created a small example to demonstrate:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primarystage) throws Exception
    {
        // Create layout
        VBox root = new VBox();

        TableView<TableObject> table = new TableView<TableObject>();
        TableColumn<TableObject, String> col1 = new TableColumn<TableObject, String>("Column 1");
        TableColumn<TableObject, String> col2 = new TableColumn<TableObject, String>("Column 2");
        table.getColumns().addAll(col1, col2);

        col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableObject, String>("column1"));
        col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableObject, String>("column2"));
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

        root.getChildren().add(table);

        ScrollPane scrollpane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollpane.setFitToWidth(true);
        scrollpane.setFitToHeight(true);
        scrollpane.setPrefSize(500, 200);
        scrollpane.setContent(root);

        // Create and show scene            
        Scene scene = new Scene(scrollpane);
        primarystage.setScene(scene);
        primarystage.show();

        // Populate table
        ArrayList<TableObject> data = new ArrayList<TableObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20;)
        {
            TableObject entry = new TableObject(String.valueOf(i++), String.valueOf(i++));
            data.add(entry);
        }

        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data));
    }

    public class TableObject
    {
        private StringProperty column1;
        private StringProperty column2;

        public TableObject(String col1, String col2)
        {
            column1 = new SimpleStringProperty(col1);
            column2 = new SimpleStringProperty(col2);
        }

        public StringProperty column1Property()
        {
            return column1;
        }

        public StringProperty column2Property()
        {
            return column2;
        }
    }
}
```

The result is this:

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Is there perhaps something I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: I tried running your example and the output seems to be alright. [Check this out](http://pbrd.co/1maZRbg)

Comment: Wow, this is actually really worrying now. If code is going to be inconsistent. Thanks for checking, any ideas? Javafx versions or something?

Comment: There can be various reasons. Which JavaFX version are you using ? I tried it on `Java 1.8.0 b-132` on Mac

Comment: Java 1.8.0_05, Windows 8.1

Comment: I do not have windows 8.1, but if you come across the issue again, raise a [JIRA]( https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa) for the JAVAFX dev team

Comment: Will do, busy compiling a list of things like this. But thanks for your time

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Wondering what was at the dead link, did you see them aligned correctly with this exact example? Just tried and see the initial misalignment in all versions fx8, fx11, fx18+ - all fine if the stage is shown after setting the items. Which might not be possible always, so I would consider this behavior a bug.

Comment: I've noticed this for years.  The scrollbar messes up the alignment, but it snaps back as soon as you actually scroll.

Answer (score 0):

just show the stage *after* setting table items:

```
stage.show();        
table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data));
```

Comment: the stage _is_ shown - or how would s/he have a made a screenshot :) Please read the code thoroughly (note: the relative sequence of show vs. setItems doesn't matter)

Comment: I was wrong - here sequence _does_ matter ;)  Edited to revert the vote (and format the code vs. bolding it)

Comment: That's not always possible.  What if the data for the table is retrieved from a background thread?

Comment: Then you have to calculate how many rows you have and if the ScrollPane will be active based on the window size and set the value of scaleX of the col dynamically